# SQLite cascading delete

Tags: sql, cascading-deletes

The parent table is:

```
CREATE TABLE BHEAD (
ID INTEGER primary key asc,
DESCR TEXT,
LINECTR INT,
UNITCTR INT)
```

The child table is:

```
CREATE TABLE BDET (
ID INTEGER primary key asc,
BID INTEGER,
BCODE TEXT,
QTY INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY (BID) REFERENCES BHEAD(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

I also execute the SQL `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;`.
However, it does not work; when I delete one row from `BHEAD`, its associated rows in `BDET` are not gone...

Why was that?

Answer (score 1):

What version of SQLite are you using?

Please see: [Foreign Keys](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable%3E).

> In order to use foreign key constraints in SQLite, the library must be compiled with neither SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY or SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER defined.

Comment: I have not been able to get it to work with SQLite3 version 3.6.12, but with the specified pragma in the client it does work in SQLite3 version 3.7.8.

Answer (score 0):

> However, you can also implement on delete cascade to delete all child
> rows when a parent row is deleted.

```
-- Create the test tables using ON DELETE CASCADE
DROP TABLE t3 PURGE;
--DROP TABLE t2 PURGE;
--DROP TABLE t1 PURGE;

CREATE TABLE t1 (
  id           NUMBER,
  description  VARCHAR2(50),
  CONSTRAINT t1_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE t2 (
  id             NUMBER,
  t1_id          NUMBER,
  description    VARCHAR2(50),
  CONSTRAINT t2_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT t2_t1_fk FOREIGN KEY (t1_id) REFERENCES t1 (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE t3 (
  id             NUMBER,
  t2_id          NUMBER,
  description    VARCHAR2(50),
  CONSTRAINT t3_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT t3_t2_fk FOREIGN KEY (t2_id) REFERENCES t2 (id)
);


INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1, 't1 ONE');

INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1, 1, 't2 ONE');
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (2, NULL, 't2 TWO');

INSERT INTO t3 VALUES (1, 1, 't3 ONE');
INSERT INTO t3 VALUES (2, NULL, 't3 TWO');
COMMIT;


SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1) AS t1_count,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t2) AS t2_count,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t3) AS t3_count
FROM   dual;

DELETE FROM t3;

rollback;

truncate table t1 ;

rollback;

truncate table t1 CASCADE;
```